# Необходимость тире: "за свою авоську — и идет"

Tags: пунктуация

Сомневаюсь в необходимости тире. Вот такое предложение: "Как только в их район какая машина с товаром придет, колхозная или частная, так дед за свою авоську — и идет, авось, мол, что и достанется". Меня интересует знак препинания перед "и идет". По поводу тире не уверен.

Comment: Все верно, никакой другой знак, кроме тире, не передаст иронию этого высказывания.

Comment: Да, это нарочно. Смысл в том, что дед считал свою авоську и слово "авось" счастливыми.  
К тому же, это из письма в редакцию, тут о литературном слоге речь не идет.

Comment: @grumant Не нужно писать текст заголовочным шрифтом.

Comment: А может это и мои опечатки от "неправильного движка"?
на всамом деля я всегда стараюсь выправлять. По разным причинам не всегда удается следлать это сразу, но я всега благодарю за указание на мои опечатки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире в этом случае ставится, если имеет место быстрая смена событий или неожиданное присоединение. В Вашем предложении есть и то, и другое